# SQL stored procedure call failed with index out of range

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server from my java code. This stored procedure is used in some other language and it was working fine from long back. Now I need to integrate it in my java app. I have 15 columns in my table. When I tried this in my java code, its throwing
**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 11 is out of range**
I also see **"Error: 0, SQLState: S1093"**

**My stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[user_input_sp] 

@Username   VARCHAR(10)=NULL, 
@UserKey    VARCHAR(50)=NULL, 
@ReqTime    DATETIME=null, 
@ResTime    DATETIME=null, 
@Req            TEXT=null,
@Res            TEXT=null,
@condition      TEXT=null,
@ID             INT=null,
@Address        VARCHAR(8000) = NULL,
@Task           VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@Direction          INT=0, 
@Seq                INT=0, 
@RR                 BIT=0, 
@Correction         VARCHAR(8) = NULL,
@PendingTrans   VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@ForwardID          VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@Command        VARCHAR(50) = NULL


AS  
    DECLARE @TSqno int
    @IF @Direction=0
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE Basp_NewKey 'web_log', @TSqno OUTPUT
        Insert into cbscne dbo WebServiceLog( Order, US_Name, US_Key , US_ReqD, US_ResD, US_Req , US_Res, cond, ID ,Address, Task, Command)
        values (@TSqno, @Username, @UserKey, @ReqTime, @ResTime, @Req ,@Res, @condition, @ID ,@Address, @Task ,@Command)
    END
.......
```

**My java code**

```
public vold addWebServiceLogRequest(UserInput cd){
 sessionFactory = sqlServerEMFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class); 
 Session sessionForSave = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
 sessionForSave.beginTransaction(); 

    sessionForSave.doReturningWork(connection-> {
        try(CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call user_input_sp(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}")) { 
            cstmt.setInt("indicator", 0); 
            cstmt.setString("Username",cd.getInterfaceName()); 
            cstmt.setInt("User_code",cd.getCaseId()); 
            cstmt.setTimestamp("RetrieveDate",cd.getRequestDate()); 
            cstmt.setTimestamp("ReturnDate",cd.getResponseDate()); 
            cstmt.setString("Req",cd.getRequestxml()); 
            cstmt.setString("Res",cd.getResponsexml()); 
            cstmt.setString("Task",cd.getTask()); 
            cstmt.setString("flow",null); 
            cstmt.execute(); 
            cstmt.close(); 
            connection.close(); 
            return null; 

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. I'd avoid using them in future code.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? `cstmt.set...()` or `cstmt.execute()`?

Comment: its throwing from cstmt.execute() method

Comment: It doesn't look like SQL Server error.

Comment: I doubt if the column mapping is incorrect

Comment: I don't think all of your variables are defined in the stored procedure  -- (@TSqno, @WSR_esponse, )

Comment: '@TSqno is created just before if block. Typo in '@Res variable here. Corrected it now